# Read data from binary file python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a binary file with this format:

[image]

and i use this code to open it:

```
import numpy as np

f = open("author_1", "r")

dt = np.dtype({'names': ['au_id','len_au_name','au_name','nu_of_publ', 'pub_id', 'len_of_pub_id','pub_title','num_auth','len_au_name_1', 'au_name1','len_au_name_2', 'au_name2','len_au_name_3', 'au_name3','year_publ','num_of_cit','citid','len_cit_tit','cit_tit', 'num_of_au_cit','len_cit_au_name_1','au_cit_name_1', len_cit_au_name_2',
'au_cit_name_2','len_cit_au_name_3','au_cit_name_3','len_cit_au_name_4',
'au_cit_name_4', 'len_cit_au_name_5','au_cit_name_5','year_cit'],
         'formats': [int,int,'S13',int,int,int,'S61',          int,int,'S8',int,'S7',int,'S12',int,int,int,int,'S50',int,int,
                'S7',int,'S7',int,'S9',int,'S8',int,'S1',int]})
a = np.fromfile(f, dtype=dt, count=-1, sep="")
```

And I take this:

```
array([ (1, 13, b'Scott Shenker', 200, 1, 61, b'Integrated services in the internet architecture: an overview', 3, 8, b'R Braden', 7, b'D Clark', 12, b'S Shenker\xe2\x80\xa6', 1994, 1000, 401, 50, b'[HTML] An architecture for differentiated services', 5, 7, b'D Black', 7, b'S Blake', 9, b'M Carlson', 8, b'E Davies', 1, b'Z', 1998),
(402, 72, b'Resource rese', 1952544370, 544108393, 1953460848, b'ocol (RSVP)--Version 1 functional specification\x05\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00R Brad', 487013, 541851648, b'Zhang\x08', 1109414656, b'erson\x08', 542310400, b'Herzog\x07\x00\x00\x00S ', 1768776010, 511342, 103168, 22016, b'\x00A reliable multicast framework for light-weight s', 1769173861, 544435823, b'and app', 1633905004, b'tion le', 543974774, b'framing\x04', 458752, b'\x00\x00S Floy', 2660, b'', 1632247894),
```

Any idea how can open the whole file?

Comment: To clarify: you only know how to read the first record from the file and you want to be able to read all of the records?

Comment: Consider using Python's standard file reading methods and the `struct` module instead.

Comment: Notice that to read the third element (author's name) and *everything beyond it* properly, you have to read the second element and dynamically use that length.  Right now you've hardcoded it, which is very bad - you will have to make a more complicated dynamic reader, just using numpy won't ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Ryan: parsing the data is straightforward, but not trivial, and really tedious. Whatever disk space saving you gain by packing the data in this way, you pay it dearly at the hour of unpacking.

Anyway, the file is made of variable length records and fields. Each record is made of variable number and length of fields that we can read in chunks of bytes. Each chunk will have different format. You get the idea. Following this logic, I assembled these three functions, that you can finish, modify, test, etc:

```
from struct import Struct
import struct

def read_chunk(fmt, fileobj):
    chunk_struct = Struct(fmt)
    chunk = fileobj.read(chunk_struct.size)
    return chunk_struct.unpack(chunk)

def read_record(fileobj):
    author_id, len_author_name = read_chunk('ii', f)
    author_name, nu_of_publ = read_chunk(str(len_author_name)+'ci', f) # 's' or 'c' ?
    record = {  'author_id': author_id,
                'author_name': author_name,
                'publications': [] }
    for pub in range(nu_of_publ):
        pub_id, len_pub_title = read_chunk('ii', f)
        pub_title, num_pub_auth = read_chunk(str(len_pub_title)+'ci', f)
        record['publications'].append({
                'publication_id': pub_id,
                'publication_title': pub_title,
                'publication_authors': [] })
        for auth in range(num_pub_auth):
            len_pub_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)
            pub_auth_name = read_chunk(str(len_pub_auth_name)+'c', f)
            record['publications']['publication_authors'].append({'name': pub_auth_name})
        year_publ, nu_of_cit = read_chunk('ii', f)
        # Finish building your record with the remaining fields...
        for cit in range(nu_of_cit):
            cit_id, len_cit_title = read_chunk('ii', f)
            cit_title, num_cit_auth = read_chunk(str(len_cit_title)+'ci', f)
        for cit_auth in range(num_cit_auth):
            len_cit_auth_name = read_chunk('i', f)
            cit_auth_name = read_chunk(str(len_cit_auth_name)+'c', f)
        year_cit_publ = read_chunk('i', f)
    return record

def parse_file(filename):
    records = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                records.append(read_record(f))
            except struct.error:
                break
    # do something useful with the records...
```

Comment: i tested it and take this result: AttributeError: type object 'Struct' has no attribute 'error' .   Any idea what's wrong

Comment: you need an `import struct` at the beginning too.

Comment: For the strings, I don't know if `s` or `c` is the correct choice: now it is using `s`. like in `61s`. Read the documentation for struct's [format characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). Besides, you may need to `.decode()` the strings.

Comment: chapelo please help. can i send you the binary file to tell me  what's wrong, because i can't solve the problem.

Comment: Above is binary file with this format. If anybody can help.

Comment: @lefbar What have you tried in these 25+ days? Where are you stuck? I could read your 4.8MB file and it has 1 author with 200 publications, which in JSON format uses only 7.1MB and it is way easier to read. And if you zip the file, it takes less than 2MB. I don't want to just give you the answer, tell me where you are having trouble. Use the `read_chunk` function to parse one by one, integers or array of chars (use `c`, not `s`). You could even make a `read_integer` and a `read_string` function to help you. The process is painstaking, but straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure stored in this file is hierarchical, rather than "flat": child arrays of different length are stored within each parent element. It is not possible to represent such a data structure using numpy arrays (even recarrays), and therefore it is not possible to read the file with `np.fromfile()`.

What do you mean by "open the whole file"? What sort of python data structure would you like to end up with?

It would be straightforward, but still not trivial, to write a function to parse the file into a list of dictionaries.